# Angular slow to build an array on Android device

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I have a simple array that takes rows from a database and assigns a distance column as a key.

```
let output = {};
for (let dataRow of sqllite.rows) {
    output[dataRow.distance] = dataRow;
}
```

In testing in Chrome browser on PC, it takes less than a second to complete, but on an Android device, it just hangs.

What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

After a stab in the dark, this fixed it. Changing from Typescript to Javascript.

```
let output = {};
for (var outputIndex in sqllite.rows) {
   output[sqllite.rows[outputIndex].distance] = sqllite.rows.rows[outputIndex];
}
```

No idea why TS is slower